# Fluent NHibernate 1.2 with SubclassMap causes "No row with the given identifier" error

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I am trying to upgrade to Fluent NHibernate 2.1 (Build #694). As a result, I am also upgrading to NHibernate 3.0.  I am having an issue with a "Table-Per-Subclass" mapping, which results in error when trying to retrieve data.

**Important Note:** these tables and classes worked with the now deprecated version of "Joined-Subclass" mapping which existed in a previous version of FluentNhibernate, which allowed the subclass to have its own unique id.

I have whittled the code down to its smallest parts, so let me explain, via code and it will become more clear:

Here are the tables involved:

[image: Tables]

Here are the classes representing the tables:

```
public class Field
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
public class MenuItem : Field
{
    public virtual string NavigateUrl { get; set; }
}
public class UserLink 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string ExternalLinkName { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the corresponding Mappings:

```
public class FieldMap : ClassMap<Field>
{
    public FieldMap()
    {
        Table("Field");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Code, "Code");
        Map(x => x.Description, "Description");
    }
}
public class MenuItemMap : SubclassMap<MenuItem>
{
    public MenuItemMap()
    {
        Table("MenuItem");
        Map(x => x.NavigateUrl, "NavigateUrl");
    }
}
public class UserLinkMap : ClassMap<UserLink>
{
    public UserLinkMap()
    {
        Table("UserLink");
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.ExternalLinkName, "ExternalLinkName");
        Map(x => x.UserId, "User_ID");
        References(x => x.MenuItem).Column("ID");
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
[Test]
    public void CanRetrieveUserLinks()
    {
        ISession session = GetSession();

        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof (UserLink))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserId", 1));

        ICriteria executableCriteria = criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session);
        var userLinks = executableCriteria.List<UserLink>();

        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLinks[0].MenuItem.NavigateUrl));

        session.Close();
    }
```

When the Assert line is executed, the SQL generated is incorrect as it **tries to lookup the MenuItem by Field_ID instead of ID**. Therefore, I receive the error: `NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists[AS.AIMS.DomainModel.MenuItem#11]`

First the sql is generated to retrieve the userLinks, which is correct:

```
SELECT this_.ID               as ID2_0_,
   this_.ExternalLinkName as External2_2_0_,
   this_.User_ID          as User3_2_0_
   FROM   UserLink this_
  WHERE  this_.User_ID = 1 /* @p0 */
```

Then to retrieve the Menu Item, it uses Field_Id instead of ID:

```
SELECT menuitem0_.Field_id      as ID0_0_,
   menuitem0_1_.Code        as Code0_0_,
   menuitem0_1_.Description as Descript3_0_0_,
   menuitem0_.NavigateUrl   as Navigate2_1_0_
  FROM   MenuItem menuitem0_
 inner join Field menuitem0_1_
         on menuitem0_.Field_id = menuitem0_1_.ID
 WHERE  menuitem0_.Field_id = 11 /* @p0 */
```

Comment: fluent 1.2 / nh3.1 went live today. http://fluentnhibernate.org/blog/2011/04/03/fluent-nhibernate-1.2-released

Comment: This isn't your full code, is it? What does menuitem subclassmap from?

Comment: MenuItem is a subclass from Field.  This is defined in the class declaration: `public class MenuItem : Field`

Comment: Kohan - In the downloads section of the FluentNhibernate site, I did not see a link for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at how i did this, and the only difference i can see is that on the database (in your case) MenuItem would only have a Field_ID. This would would relate to ID on field.

Does it work if you remove ID on MenuItem and make Field_ID the key. Like so:

```
MENUITEM                  FIELD

#Field_ID   <---------->  #ID
NavigateUrl               Code        
(Removed Code, Desc)      Description
```

Comment: So, I changed the line in UserLinkMap to: `References(x => x.MenuItem).Column("Field_ID");` and I get an error because it tries to retreive Field_ID from the UserLink table, which of course does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, i mean in your database, not the mappings. They look fine to me.

Comment: Kohan - Thanks for your help, this appears to work as expected. I guess I am wondering if what I had previously is just wrong or it can be accomplished in another manner?  I would like the MenuItem table to have its own unique identifier.  I ask because this little sample I have is a very simple version of the real world application which is much larger, and making changes to the tables and the mappings in this way would be a very large effort.

Comment: It would still have a unique "ID", Field_ID. I'm starting to think that you don't want to be using a subclass. May i ask why it is?

Comment: @Kohan - essentially, having a unique identifier for each table has become sort of a standard.  Foreign keys can also be used, we just generally do not use them as the primary key. So, it would be nice to have something that will inherently save the Field record as well as the MenuItem record when saving a MenuItem. In addition, this all worked with JoinedSubClass and the previous Fluent version.

Comment: I believe if MenuItem is truly a subclass of Field, then it's unique ID would be Field_ID.